# What is the use or meaning of restore functionality in app billing v3 in android

Tags: android, restore, billing

I am implementing in-app billing v3 in android application.I can purchased the test product successfully.
But in my application there are restore functionality also,I am little bit confusing.

Is it right that in other device application will load all owned item in our application?

Comment: I think it looks like a must. you have to be able restore your owned products in another device. It has to be device independent !

Comment: Thanks @osayilgan, I think google play maintain the in app purchased  item based on google email address of user.Is is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are consuming in-app products from google play which is connected with your gmail account, then it's all about your google play account.

Here is a sample method to give you an idea about how it works. I use it in one of my applications.

```
/**
 * Gets the list of available inventories in GooglePlay for this application
 * 
 * @param productIdList             list of product id's in the store
 *                                  if null, will return owned items only
 * @param inventoryListListener     OnQueryInventoryFinishedListener
 */
public void getInventoryList(List<String> productIdList, InvetoryListInterface inventoryListListener) {

    final InvetoryListInterface listener = inventoryListListener;

    inAppBillingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(productIdList, new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventroy) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Failure getting inventory list.
                listener.onInventoryListFailure(result.getMessage());
                return;
            } else {
                // Success getting inventory list.
                listener.onInventoryListSuccess(inventroy);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It should be working, I use the same way in my existing application.